# Using the Minto Pyramid

Tags: technical-writing, academic-writing, organization, outline

[image: http://www.12manage.com/images/picture_minto_pyramid_principle.gif]

Using the Minto Pyramid, should I order the paragraphs of my paper by going through the rows of the pyramid like this?

Thesis > Why > How > Where > A > B > C > D > E

Or should I start at the top of the pyramid and follow one branch down to the end leaf, then go up one step and repeat?

Thesis > Why > A > B > How > C > D > Where > E

Comment: I would think the latter, at least in the general case, to avoid the gap between, say, **Why** and **A** & **B**. But I don't think there's a one-size-fits-all answer; it could depend on a number of factors, such as the topic or the length of the work.

Comment: I think the more complete answer would be to discuss all necessary dependencies (maybe _B_ is imperative for understanding _Why_ while _A_ isn't as much) and save the other low-level points for an 'Origins' or 'Development' section that's to come after the higher-level ones are finished.

Comment: How large a paper?  How many "nodes" at each level?  How many cross-dependencies?  These are all factors that seem relevant.

Comment: The paper will be between 2-5 pages. With about 6 nodes at the 2nd level and around 2 child nodes for each of those. Only 3 levels, including Thesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the latter option, **Thesis > Why > A > B > How > C > D > Where > E**. As commenters have mentioned, it's probably best to keep the gap between A,B, and Why as short as possible.

This structure also lends itself more easily to formatting, and it should also cut down on the number of cross-references you need to make from one section to the next (as you're likely able to discuss the Why, How, and Where mostly independently from each other).

Comment: Welcome to Writers.SE! In general this is good advice, but it applies to pretty much any structure/outline. For a question like this, we'd look for specific advice on the choice the Original Poster is asking about - sure, either way _can_ work and no outline will work perfectly, but what might work better or worse? Are there any considerations to choose one or the other? Can you give examples that demonstrate good or bad choices?

Comment: In general, if you think the *question* is poor, vague, unanswerable, or just a generic "any of those can work just fine," - IMHO that works better as comments (and votes!) on the question, than as an answer.